# C# Using task and yield to keep UI informed of a running process

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task, yield

Is it bad practice to write code like this. What I want to accomplish is that a user can press a button on a control. The button starts some kind of analyzing process and for each item done it shows a result to the user.

```
private IEnumerable<int> AnalyzeItems() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    yield return i;
  }
}


private void PerformTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Task.Run(() => {
    foreach (var item in AnalyzeItems()) {
      ResultLog.Invoke((Action)delegate() { ResultLog.Text += item.ToString(); });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Apart from not being able to catch exceptions, it might be a good fit for your needs. It depends on how many elements you have and how much work. If every element takes less than a couple of hundred milliseconds then you might get freeze, so be careful here.

Comment: Is the analyzing process I/O work or CPU work? If the former, then you shouldn't use `Task.Run`; just use regular `async/await`.

Comment: Its CPU work. I always though that async await is also using Tasks and it was just sugarcoating and helping merging back to the thread. I'll look into what the difference is. Thx for the info. @Fcin: why would I get a freeze if each element is just a few milliseconds?

Comment: Because `ResultLog.Invoke` schedules work on UI thread. The more messages you schedule on UI thread the more work it has to do between drawing controls. If it has too much work then it will not be able to draw UI and you will see freeze. If you say to UI thread "do this for me" every couple of ms then it will not have time to update screen.

Comment: Thanks @Fcin for the explanation. In the current situation no freezing occurs but it is something to keep in mind. I see that using any kind of reporting back is somekind of Invoke so it doesnt depend on the way you use it (backgroundworker / progress / invoke) it is just something always to keep in mind when reporting :). Thank you for your info I didnt think of it. Also found some info on the internet about difference of task and await async (with task). Some interesting reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your approach bad practice? It depends.

If you don't expect your code inside `Task.Run` to throw any exceptions and you want to continue doing something else, then your code is ok. However, if you want to capture any possible exceptions and wait for the process to finish without freezing UI, then you might want to consider using `async/await`.

```
private async void PerformTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        foreach (var item in AnalyzeItems()) {
            ResultLog.Invoke((Action)delegate() { ResultLog.Text += item.ToString(); });
        }
    });
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    // handle...
  }
}
```

---

Alternative approach would be to use `IProgress<T>`. This allows for easy separation of long running work and updating UI. Please note that you shouldn't call this method *too often*, because

1. This will put too much work on UI thread resulting in UI freeze.
2. If you pass any valuetype to `IProgress<T>.Report` method, then it gets copied. If you call this too often, you risk running garbage collector very often resulting in even bigger freezes.

All of this means that you should utilize `IProgress` only for truly long running work.

Now that we have it all out of the way, here is a sample of how you could notify users about progress of analyzed items:

```
private double _currentProgress;
public double CurrentProgress {
    get => _currentProgress;
    set
    {
        _currentProgress = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private async void PerformTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<double>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, p) => CurrentProgress = p;

    await Task.Run(() => AnalyzeItems(Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).ToList(), progress));
}

private void AnalyzeItems(List<int> items, IProgress<double> progress)
{
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < items.Count; itemIndex++)
    {
        // Very long running CPU work.
        // ...
        progress.Report((double)itemIndex * 100 / items.Count);
    }
}
```

If `AnalyzeItems` takes less than 100 ms for individual item, then you don't want to report after every finished item (see why above). You can decide how often you want to update status like this:

```
private void AnalyzeItems(List<int> items, IProgress<double> progress)
{
    var lastReport = DateTime.UtcNow;
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < items.Count; itemIndex++)
    {
        // Very long running work.
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        // Tell the user what the current status is every 500 milliseconds.
        if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastReport > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        {
            progress.Report((double)itemIndex * 100 / items.Count);
            lastReport = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have really a lot of very fast iterations, you may want to consider changing `DateTime.Now` to something else.

Comment: Thank you for your examples. I thought of using IProgress as an alternative to the Invoke. IProgress still invokes but its more abstract so more of use when using different kinds of GUI. Also it nicely seperates the process from the GUI. Now I'm using the yield as a progressreporter :). I will probably go to the IProgress approach with the async await and use batches of N to report progress. I'm reporting by using a POCO with info and displaying it in a grid (like a progresslog). By using batches I the GC won't be to hefty and I reduce the amount of invokes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

why do not use [Backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)?

First setup the backgroundworker properties to:

- WorkerReportsProgress = true
- WorkerSupportsCancellation = true

This is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending) {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i / 10, "step " + i);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cancelButton.Focus();
        button1.Enabled = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        if (e.Error != null) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Unexpected error");
        }
        if (e.Cancelled) {
            MessageBox.Show("Process stopped by the user", "Cancelled");
        }
        label1.Text = "Press start";
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since using async await and tasks I'm not using the backgroundworker anymore. My other idea was using the IProgress 9https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) to report back. But I thought it was kinda neat to use the yield in combination with a task because of it being less code. I also thought that the async await was a way for Microsoft to replace the backgroundworker?